# How to fixed the header of the table in the page?

Tags: codeigniter, html-table

This is my view page:
[image]

In this page when the scroll the entire page in chrome the header of the table should be fixed only content should be scrolled.I have searched many codes in google but it not working.

My table code:

```
    <table id="customers" >
            <thead>
                <tr>

<th>MillCode</th>
<th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
    <tr>
<td><a href="<?=site_url('Sales/Sales_Edit/'.$row['millcode'])?>"><?=$row['mname']?></td>
<td  dir="rtl"><a href="<?=site_url('Sales/Sales_Edit/'.$row['millcode'])?>"><?php echo number_format($row['amount']);?></td>

                </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your table under a div `<div class="table-wrapper"></div>` and apply this css.

```
div.table-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
 table,thead,tr,th {
   text-align: left;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0px;
   background-color: #666;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: i used your code but it has got 2 scroll bar one for that page another for that table

Comment: Try changing this div.table-wrapper to .table-wrapper in css.

Comment: i changed same answer only i got it

Comment: Check your code for any other class reference .table-wrapper, specially on body tag

Comment: I've searched all over the Internet for a solution to this issue. Finally, this solution worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick header using javaScript

```
  **HTML**

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
             <h1>Sticky Table Headers</h1>

        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped sticky-header">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>New Table</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

CSS 

body {
    padding-top:50px;
}
table.floatThead-table {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

JS


// @preserve jQuery.floatThead 1.2.9 - http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ - Copyright (c) 2012 - 2014 Misha Koryak
// @license MIT
! function (a) {
    function b(a, b, c) {
        if (8 == g) {
            var d = j.width(),
                e = f.debounce(function () {
                    var a = j.width();
                    d != a && (d = a, c())
                }, a);
            j.on(b, e)
        } else j.on(b, f.debounce(c, a))
    }

    function c(a) {
        window.console && window.console && window.console.log && window.console.log(a)
    }

    function d() {
        var b = a('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow-y:scroll;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;width:100%"></div>');
        a("body").append(b);
        var c = b.innerWidth(),
            d = a("div", b).innerWidth();
        return b.remove(), c - d
    }

    function e(a) {
        if (a.dataTableSettings) for (var b = 0; b < a.dataTableSettings.length; b++) {
            var c = a.dataTableSettings[b].nTable;
            if (a[0] == c) return !0
        }
        return !1
    }
    a.floatThead = a.floatThead || {}, a.floatThead.defaults = {
        cellTag: null,
        headerCellSelector: "tr:first>th:visible",
        zIndex: 1001,
        debounceResizeMs: 10,
        useAbsolutePositioning: !0,
        scrollingTop: 0,
        scrollingBottom: 0,
        scrollContainer: function () {
            return a([])
        },
        getSizingRow: function (a) {
            return a.find("tbody tr:visible:first>*")
        },
        floatTableClass: "floatThead-table",
        floatWrapperClass: "floatThead-wrapper",
        floatContainerClass: "floatThead-container",
        copyTableClass: !0,
        debug: !1
    };
    var f = window._,
        g = function () {
            for (var a = 3, b = document.createElement("b"), c = b.all || []; a = 1 + a, b.innerHTML = "<\!--[if gt IE " + a + "]><i><![endif]-->", c[0];);
            return a > 4 ? a : document.documentMode
        }(),
        h = null,
        i = function () {
            if (g) return !1;
            var b = a("<table><colgroup><col></colgroup><tbody><tr><td style='width:10px'></td></tbody></table>");
            a("body").append(b);
            var c = b.find("col").width();
            return b.remove(), 0 == c
        }, j = a(window),
        k = 0;
    a.fn.floatThead = function (l) {
        if (l = l || {}, !f && (f = window._ || a.floatThead._, !f)) throw new Error("jquery.floatThead-slim.js requires underscore. You should use the non-lite version since you do not have underscore.");
        if (8 > g) return this;
        if (null == h && (h = i(), h && (document.createElement("fthtr"), document.createElement("fthtd"), document.createElement("fthfoot"))), f.isString(l)) {
            var m = l,
                n = this;
            return this.filter("table").each(function () {
                var b = a(this).data("floatThead-attached");
                if (b && f.isFunction(b[m])) {
                    var c = b[m]();
                    "undefined" != typeof c && (n = c)
                }
            }), n
        }
        var o = a.extend({}, a.floatThead.defaults || {}, l);
        return a.each(l, function (b) {
            b in a.floatThead.defaults || !o.debug || c("jQuery.floatThead: used [" + b + "] key to init plugin, but that param is not an option for the plugin. Valid options are: " + f.keys(a.floatThead.defaults).join(", "))
        }), this.filter(":not(." + o.floatTableClass + ")").each(function () {
            function c(a) {
                return a + ".fth-" + y + ".floatTHead"
            }

            function i() {
                var b = 0;
                A.find("tr:visible").each(function () {
                    b += a(this).outerHeight(!0)
                }), Z.outerHeight(b), $.outerHeight(b)
            }

            function l() {
                var a = z.outerWidth(),
                    b = I.width() || a;
                if (X.width(b - F.vertical), O) {
                    var c = 100 * a / (b - F.vertical);
                    S.css("width", c + "%")
                } else S.outerWidth(a)
            }

            function m() {
                C = (f.isFunction(o.scrollingTop) ? o.scrollingTop(z) : o.scrollingTop) || 0, D = (f.isFunction(o.scrollingBottom) ? o.scrollingBottom(z) : o.scrollingBottom) || 0
            }

            function n() {
                var b, c;
                if (V) b = U.find("col").length;
                else {
                    var d;
                    d = null == o.cellTag && o.headerCellSelector ? o.headerCellSelector : "tr:first>" + o.cellTag, c = A.find(d), b = 0, c.each(function () {
                        b += parseInt(a(this).attr("colspan") || 1, 10)
                    })
                }
                if (b != H) {
                    H = b;
                    for (var e = [], f = [], g = [], i = 0; b > i; i++) e.push('<th class="floatThead-col"/>'), f.push("<col/>"), g.push("<fthtd style='display:table-cell;height:0;width:auto;'/>");
                    f = f.join(""), e = e.join(""), h && (g = g.join(""), W.html(g), bb = W.find("fthtd")), Z.html(e), $ = Z.find("th"), V || U.html(f), _ = U.find("col"), T.html(f), ab = T.find("col")
                }
                return b
            }

            function p() {
                if (!E) {
                    if (E = !0, J) {
                        var a = z.width(),
                            b = Q.width();
                        a > b && z.css("minWidth", a)
                    }
                    z.css(db), S.css(db), S.append(A), B.before(Y), i()
                }
            }

            function q() {
                E && (E = !1, J && z.width(fb), Y.detach(), z.prepend(A), z.css(eb), S.css(eb))
            }

            function r(a) {
                J != a && (J = a, X.css({
                    position: J ? "absolute" : "fixed"
                }))
            }

            function s(a, b, c, d) {
                return h ? c : d ? o.getSizingRow(a, b, c) : b
            }

            function t() {
                var a, b = n();
                return function () {
                    var c = s(z, _, bb, g);
                    if (c.length == b && b > 0) {
                        if (!V) for (a = 0; b > a; a++) _.eq(a).css("width", "");
                        q();
                        var d = [];
                        for (a = 0; b > a; a++) d[a] = c.get(a).offsetWidth;
                        for (a = 0; b > a; a++) ab.eq(a).width(d[a]), _.eq(a).width(d[a]);
                        p()
                    } else S.append(A), z.css(eb), S.css(eb), i()
                }
            }

            function u(a) {
                var b = I.css("border-" + a + "-width"),
                    c = 0;
                return b && ~b.indexOf("px") && (c = parseInt(b, 10)), c
            }

            function v() {
                var a, b = I.scrollTop(),
                    c = 0,
                    d = L ? K.outerHeight(!0) : 0,
                    e = M ? d : -d,
                    f = X.height(),
                    g = z.offset(),
                    i = 0;
                if (O) {
                    var k = I.offset();
                    c = g.top - k.top + b, L && M && (c += d), c -= u("top"), i = u("left")
                } else a = g.top - C - f + D + F.horizontal;
                var l = j.scrollTop(),
                    m = j.scrollLeft(),
                    n = I.scrollLeft();
                return b = I.scrollTop(),

                function (k) {
                    if ("windowScroll" == k ? (l = j.scrollTop(), m = j.scrollLeft()) : "containerScroll" == k ? (b = I.scrollTop(), n = I.scrollLeft()) : "init" != k && (l = j.scrollTop(), m = j.scrollLeft(), b = I.scrollTop(), n = I.scrollLeft()), !h || !(0 > l || 0 > m)) {
                        if (R) r("windowScrollDone" == k ? !0 : !1);
                        else if ("windowScrollDone" == k) return null;
                        g = z.offset(), L && M && (g.top += d);
                        var o, s, t = z.outerHeight();
                        if (O && J) {
                            if (c >= b) {
                                var u = c - b;
                                o = u > 0 ? u : 0
                            } else o = P ? 0 : b;
                            s = i
                        } else !O && J ? (l > a + t + e ? o = t - f + e : g.top > l + C ? (o = 0, q()) : (o = C + l - g.top + c + (M ? d : 0), p()), s = 0) : O && !J ? (c > b || b - c > t ? (o = g.top - l, q()) : (o = g.top + b - l - c, p()), s = g.left + n - m) : O || J || (l > a + t + e ? o = t + C - l + a + e : g.top > l + C ? (o = g.top - l, p()) : o = C, s = g.left - m);
                        return {
                            top: o,
                            left: s
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function w() {
                var a = null,
                    b = null,
                    c = null;
                return function (d, e, f) {
                    null == d || a == d.top && b == d.left || (X.css({
                        top: d.top,
                        left: d.left
                    }), a = d.top, b = d.left), e && l(), f && i();
                    var g = I.scrollLeft();
                    J && c == g || (X.scrollLeft(g), c = g)
                }
            }

            function x() {
                if (I.length) {
                    var a = I.width(),
                        b = I.height(),
                        c = z.height(),
                        d = z.width(),
                        e = d > a ? G : 0,
                        f = c > b ? G : 0;
                    F.horizontal = d > a - f ? G : 0, F.vertical = c > b - e ? G : 0
                }
            }
            var y = k,
                z = a(this);
            if (z.data("floatThead-attached")) return !0;
            if (!z.is("table")) throw new Error('jQuery.floatThead must be run on a table element. ex: $("table").floatThead();');
            var A = z.find("thead:first"),
                B = z.find("tbody:first");
            if (0 == A.length) throw new Error("jQuery.floatThead must be run on a table that contains a <thead> element");
            var C, D, E = !1,
                F = {
                    vertical: 0,
                    horizontal: 0
                }, G = d(),
                H = 0,
                I = o.scrollContainer(z) || a([]),
                J = o.useAbsolutePositioning;
            null == J && (J = o.scrollContainer(z).length);
            var K = z.find("caption"),
                L = 1 == K.length;
            if (L) var M = "top" === (K.css("caption-side") || K.attr("align") || "top");
            var N = a('<fthfoot style="display:table-footer-group;"/>'),
                O = I.length > 0,
                P = !1,
                Q = a([]),
                R = 9 >= g && !O && J,
                S = a("<table/>"),
                T = a("<colgroup/>"),
                U = z.find("colgroup:first"),
                V = !0;
            0 == U.length && (U = a("<colgroup/>"), V = !1);
            var W = a('<fthrow style="display:table-row;height:0;"/>'),
                X = a('<div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>'),
                Y = a("<thead/>"),
                Z = a('<tr class="size-row"/>'),
                $ = a([]),
                _ = a([]),
                ab = a([]),
                bb = a([]);
            if (Y.append(Z), z.prepend(U), h && (N.append(W), z.append(N)), S.append(T), X.append(S), o.copyTableClass && S.attr("class", z.attr("class")), S.attr({
                cellpadding: z.attr("cellpadding"),
                cellspacing: z.attr("cellspacing"),
                border: z.attr("border")
            }), S.css({
                borderCollapse: z.css("borderCollapse"),
                border: z.css("border")
            }), S.addClass(o.floatTableClass).css("margin", 0), J) {
                var cb = function (a, b) {
                    var c = a.css("position"),
                        d = "relative" == c || "absolute" == c;
                    if (!d || b) {
                        var e = {
                            paddingLeft: a.css("paddingLeft"),
                            paddingRight: a.css("paddingRight")
                        };
                        X.css(e), a = a.wrap("<div class='" + o.floatWrapperClass + "' style='position: relative; clear:both;'></div>").parent(), P = !0
                    }
                    return a
                };
                O ? (Q = cb(I, !0), Q.append(X)) : (Q = cb(z), z.after(X))
            } else z.after(X);
            X.css({
                position: J ? "absolute" : "fixed",
                marginTop: 0,
                top: J ? 0 : "auto",
                zIndex: o.zIndex
            }), X.addClass(o.floatContainerClass), m();
            var db = {
                "table-layout": "fixed"
            }, eb = {
                "table-layout": z.css("tableLayout") || "auto"
            }, fb = z[0].style.width || "";
            x();
            var gb, hb = function () {
                (gb = t())()
            };
            hb();
            var ib = v(),
                jb = w();
            jb(ib("init"), !0);
            var kb = f.debounce(function () {
                jb(ib("windowScrollDone"), !1)
            }, 300),
                lb = function () {
                    jb(ib("windowScroll"), !1), kb()
                }, mb = function () {
                    jb(ib("containerScroll"), !1)
                }, nb = function () {
                    m(), x(), hb(), ib = v(), (jb = w())(ib("resize"), !0, !0)
                }, ob = f.debounce(function () {
                    x(), m(), hb(), ib = v(), jb(ib("reflow"), !0)
                }, 1);
            O ? J ? I.on(c("scroll"), mb) : (I.on(c("scroll"), mb), j.on(c("scroll"), lb)) : j.on(c("scroll"), lb), j.on(c("load"), ob), b(o.debounceResizeMs, c("resize"), nb), z.on("reflow", ob), e(z) && z.on("filter", ob).on("sort", ob).on("page", ob), z.data("floatThead-attached", {
                destroy: function () {
                    var a = ".fth-" + y;
                    q(), z.css(eb), U.remove(), h && N.remove(), Y.parent().length && Y.replaceWith(A), z.off("reflow"), I.off(a), P && (I.length ? I.unwrap() : z.unwrap()), J && z.css("minWidth", ""), X.remove(), z.data("floatThead-attached", !1), j.off(a)
                },
                reflow: function () {
                    ob()
                },
                setHeaderHeight: function () {
                    i()
                },
                getFloatContainer: function () {
                    return X
                },
                getRowGroups: function () {
                    return E ? X.find("thead").add(z.find("tbody,tfoot")) : z.find("thead,tbody,tfoot")
                }
            }), k++
        }), this
    }
}(jQuery),

function (a) {
    a.floatThead = a.floatThead || {}, a.floatThead._ = window._ || function () {
        var b = {}, c = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
            d = ["Arguments", "Function", "String", "Number", "Date", "RegExp"];
        return b.has = function (a, b) {
            return c.call(a, b)
        }, b.keys = function (a) {
            if (a !== Object(a)) throw new TypeError("Invalid object");
            var c = [];
            for (var d in a) b.has(a, d) && c.push(d);
            return c
        }, a.each(d, function () {
            var a = this;
            b["is" + a] = function (b) {
                return Object.prototype.toString.call(b) == "[object " + a + "]"
            }
        }), b.debounce = function (a, b, c) {
            var d, e, f, g, h;
            return function () {
                f = this, e = arguments, g = new Date;
                var i = function () {
                    var j = new Date - g;
                    b > j ? d = setTimeout(i, b - j) : (d = null, c || (h = a.apply(f, e)))
                }, j = c && !d;
                return d || (d = setTimeout(i, b)), j && (h = a.apply(f, e)), h
            }
        }, b
    }()
}(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".sticky-header").floatThead({
        scrollingTop: 50
    });

});
```

Comment: rather saying ***please try this***, It's better to add some code. Links might nit works in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this

HTML:

```
<table class="fixed-header" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1.0</td>
        <td>Row 1.1</td>
        <td>Row 1.2</td>
        <td>Row 1.3</td>
        <td>Row 1.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2.0</td>
        <td>Row 2.1</td>
        <td>Row 2.2</td>
        <td>Row 2.3</td>
        <td>Row 2.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3.0</td>
        <td>Row 3.1</td>
        <td>Row 3.2</td>
        <td>Row 3.3</td>
        <td>Row 3.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 4.0</td>
        <td>Row 4.1</td>
        <td>Row 4.2</td>
        <td>Row 4.3</td>
        <td>Row 4.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 5.0</td>
        <td>Row 5.1</td>
        <td>Row 5.2</td>
        <td>Row 5.3</td>
        <td>Row 5.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 6.0</td>
        <td>Row 6.1</td>
        <td>Row 6.2</td>
        <td>Row 6.3</td>
        <td>Row 6.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 7.0</td>
        <td>Row 7.1</td>
        <td>Row 7.2</td>
        <td>Row 7.3</td>
        <td>Row 7.4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-header{
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed-header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed-header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed-header th, .fixed-header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

find the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tzk9d5s7/1/